# Docker compose conditional detach on npm script

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, package.json

I want to run my node application with only one command : `npm start` and based on the `NODE_ENV`, it will either run `nodemon app.js` if `NODE_ENV=dev` or `node app.js` if `NODE_ENV=production` but in *DETACHED MODE*.

What I have so far :

package.json

```
"start": "docker-compose up --build --force-recreate api",
"api:dev": "nodemon app.js",
"api:prod": "node app.js"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["-c", "if [ \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"dev\" ]; then npm run api:dev; else npm run api:prod; fi"]
```

And finally the docker-compose file

```
api:
    restart: always
    container_name: my_api
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    ports:
        - "${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}"
    env_file: .env
    networks:
        - back
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    logging:
        options:
            max-file: "10"
            max-size: "10m"
```

Where/how can I setup the conditional detach mode? I know I should use `-d` for the detach `docker-compose up` but I want it conditional based on the `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: When you're doing actual development, do you want to just run `nodemon` directly on the host, without involving Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze No I want to use docker as well, this is a simplified version of my app that I posted there for the sake of showing the issue, the actual app is more complex and I don't want to install node on my machine